# SQLite SequelizeJs adding an extra filed in query

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am using [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) and [SQLite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3). When I use the model in my code then it is generating wrong query. Can any one help me to fix this issue

**This is my model defiantion**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    let product = sequelize.define('product', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        },
        code: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        },
        desc: {
            type: "BLOB",
        },
        productCategoryId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            references: {
                model: 'product_category',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        costPrice: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        },
        sellPrice: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        },
        markup: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        },
        markupType: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM('AMOUNT','PERCENTAGE'),
        },
        imgAttachment: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        },
        minOrderQuantity: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        },
        minStockQuantity: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        },
        isComposite: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        },
        isAllowedOutOfStockSale: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
            defaultValue: '0'
        },
        isActive: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
            defaultValue: '0'
        },
        isDeceptive: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
            defaultValue: '0'
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
        createdBy: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            references: {
                model: 'user',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        deletedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
        deletedBy: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            references: {
                model: 'user',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
        updatedBy: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            references: {
                model: 'user',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'product',
        timestamps: false,
        defaultScope: {
            where: {
                isActive: true,
                deletedAt: null,
            }
        }
    });

    // Association
    product.associate = function(models) {
        models.product.belongsTo(models.user);
        models.product.belongsTo(models.user);
        models.product.belongsTo(models.user);
        models.product.belongsTo(models.product_category);
        models.product.hasMany(models.product_composition);
    };

    return product;
}
```

**This is my model implementation**

```
models.findAll({})
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

**I am getting SequelizeDatabaseError. After investigation I trace out the generated query**

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `code`, `desc`, `productCategoryId`, `costPrice`, `sellPrice`, `markup`, `markupType`, `imgAttachment`, `minOrderQuantity`, `minStockQuantity`, `isComposite`, `isAllowedOutOfStockSale`, `isActive`, `isDeceptive`, `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `deletedAt`, `deletedBy`, `updatedAt`, `updatedBy`, `userId` FROM `product` AS `product` WHERE `product`.`id` = 1 AND `product`.`isActive` = 1 AND `product`.`deletedAt` IS NULL;
```

Why it is adding userId in query. This query works fine when I remove userId field from this generated query

Comment: Because of models.product.belongsTo(models.user) sequelize creating a foreign key userId on product model. When you use any methods on the model like findAll findOne and other methods the sequelize model constructs query based on the attributes defined and the foreign keys from the assosciation.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of this line :

This line will add a userId attribute to product to hold the primary key value for Product

```
models.product.belongsTo(models.user);
```

But This will not add the field , reason is , naming convention is followed for foreign key name `productCategoryId` but not in above case ,

```
models.product.belongsTo(models.product_category);
```

for that you should define that explicitly and you should also add alias name for association coz you are using one table for 3 relations , like

```
models.product.belongsTo(models.user , { as : 'delete_by' ,foreignKey: 'deletedBy'} );
models.product.belongsTo(models.user , { as : 'created_by' ,foreignKey: 'createdBy'} );
models.product.belongsTo(models.user , { as : 'updated_by' , foreignKey: 'updatedBy'} );
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)**